# reckless endangerment

Tags: beit-din-court, torts-damages, danger

Is it possible to bring someone to beit din on the charge of *reckless endangerment*?

If so - what is the correct terminology to describe this sort of crime?

Let's define *reckless endangerment* according to the [US Legal Definition](https://definitions.uslegal.com/r/reckless-endangerment/):

> Reckless endangerment is a crime consisting of acts that create a substantial risk of serious physical injury to another person. The accused person isn't required to intend the resulting or potential harm, but must have acted in a way that showed a disregard for the foreseeable consequences of the actions. The charge may occur in various contexts, such as, among others, domestic cases, car accidents, construction site accidents, testing sites, domestic/child abuse situations, and hospital abuse. State laws and penalties vary, so local laws should be consulted.

Comment: Can it be considered reckless endangerment if there are no damages caused?

Comment: "potential harm"

Comment: Beis din themselves were in charge of this. They would go around town seeing who's trees were going to fall into the public domain and who's wall would soon fall there. The owners were warned. If they didn't comply b.d. Hired laborers and charged the property owner.

Comment: if there are damages it is peshia.

Comment: @user6591 - interesting! I'm trying to extrapolate to the actual case I have in mind, but falling short (terrible joke on your answer, I know).

Specifically - consider a case where the situation is now avoided, but due to "luck".  Sadly, it involves a parent neglecting to inform babysitters, counselors, etc. about their young child's history of sexual misbehavior toward others and consequently the child was left to play with other children without the required addditional shmira. They didn't act out, but very well could have. I believe the parents have committed some crime of endangerment

Comment: @davidkomer there is no real money damages in hindsight. What I mentioned was Beis Din helping to avoid problems before they happen. Your case is very scary and sad, but first of all most batei dinim don't wield the power of the community the way they once did so forcing people to take certain actions, especially preventative actions, is no simple feat. Second of all cases of sexual misconduct are not really handled well in b.d. imho. I've had personal knowledge of cases where b.d. and local rabbis have had very different ideas then most of us would.